# failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, python

After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, my Python installation does not work anymore.

Running Poetry gives the following :

```bash
➜  ~ poetry
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/home/guillaume/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/guillaume/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/home/guillaume/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007ff0fb4b1040 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Running python itself does work :

```bash
➜  ~ python3
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I tried :

- Reinstalling Python
- unsetting `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH`

How can I fix my Python setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for future reference.

I overlooked the obvious. The issue had to do with Poetry. Reinstalling Poetry fixed the issue.